# PHP: deserialize Java's BigInteger

Tags: php, biginteger

In Java I create a base36 string from binary data like this:

```
String data = new BigInteger(binaryData).toString(36); 
// returns something like: 1orzkii2bst4o0yi5npnbq9bxxh22tn1xnfrpubisntoq7ilwbc63
```

Note that `BigInteger` handles data as big-endian order.

Now I want to receive the generated `data` string in PHP, and get it's original binary content. How can one achieve this? I came across the `GMP` functions, but till now I didn't have any luck.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php should help to reverse the `.toString(36)` part. Result in this case would be 8242004602246222060826228426804866484440466482280868428404260688, is that the number you are looking for already maybe?

Comment: Well, `base_convert` handles numbers and does not really output binary data. I don't think it's suitable in this case.

Comment: `gmp_export(gmp_init("1orzkii2bst4o0yi5npnbq9bxxh22tn1xnfrpubisntoq7ilwbc63", 36));`?

Comment: Thanks @e.dan that seems to work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
gmp_export(gmp_init("1orzkii2bst4o0yi5npnbq9bxxh22tn1xnfrpubisntoq7ilwbc63", 36));
```

Comment: In combination with adding `GMP_BIG_ENDIAN` this worked :)